# How to translate from EQUIVALENCE to index offset

Tags: fortran, equivalence

I am trying to modernize a Fortran 77 codebase which makes heavy use of `common` blocks in `include` files. One of my goals is to translate the codebase so it uses `modules` instead of this `common`/`include` construction. However, the code also uses `equivalence` statements here and there, referring to `common` variables. It is not allowed to `equivalence` to/from `module` variables, so this is a problem.

Now, luckily, the `equivalence` statements are only used to alias (parts of) arrays and never for 'magic' between different variables types. Therefore I have tried to translate the code by simply calculating index offsets and referring to the original arrays instead of `equivalenc`-ing them. However, this has lead to some unexpected compilation errors and runtime crashes.

For example, consider the change from

```
IF(RLX*ABS(DXT/(X2-X1)) .GT. 0.05) RLX = 0.05*ABS((X2-X1)/DXT)
```

to

```
IF(RLX*ABS(DXT/(COM2(1)-COM1(1))) .GT. 0.05) RLX = 0.05*ABS((COM2(1)-COM1(1))/DXT)
```

, which is supposed to change the `include` file code from

```
REAL COM1(NCOM), COM2(NCOM)
COMMON/V_VAR1/ X1
COMMON/V_VAR2/ X2
EQUIVALENCE (X1, COM1(1)), (X2, COM2(1))
```

to simply

```
COMMON COM1(NCOM), COM2(NCOM)
```

, but leads to the following compilation error:

```
       IF(RLX*ABS(DXT/(COM2(1)-COM1(1))) .GT. 0.05) RLX = 0.05*ABS((COM2(1)-COM1(1))/DXT)
                                                                        1
Error: Missing ')' in statement at or before (1)
```

This statement seems correct to me, though. So what am I missing here?

If I alleviate the above problem by changing the code to

```
DX = COM2(1) - COM1(1)
IF(RLX*ABS(DXT/DX) .GT. 0.05) RLX = 0.05*ABS(DX/DXT)
```

I do not get compilation errors. However, then I run into `Signal: SIGFPE (Arithmetic exception)`'s at runtime, because for some reason the change from `X1` to `COM1(1)` and `X2` to `COM2(1)` leads to seemingly unrelated variables to not get proper initial values (which leads to division by zero, and consequently to the addition of nan's, and therefore to the arithmetic exception).

Obviously, I am missing something crucial here, so I tried to find a good reference for doing this sort of translation. Does anyone know of something like that? Or has anyone run into this problem before and found a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding extra characters to a line can easily push a line length beyond the limit, so please check how long that new line is.  Also, the "simplified" single line is very different from the three lines it replaces, having `ncom` times the number of numeric storage units specified in the common block.

Comment: Are you restricted to fixed format you can you use free format in the new code? If you are modernizing the code, I don’t see any sense in writing it in fixed format again.

Comment: Also consider modernizing all the CAPITAL letters and the ugly `.GT.` to `>`. But I do agree one should not change too much at once before testing the change. I also agree that your error looks like a line length limit issue (plenty of duplicates available).

Comment: @francescalus The new line is 89 characters long, so I don't think that ought to be a problem, right? I don't understand what you mean about the simplification of the include file code. In the original code, there were two arrays of type `real` and length `ncom`, `com1` and `com2`, the first elements of which were equivalenced to two `real`s, `x1` and `x2`. In the simplified case, there are only the `com1` and `com2` arrays, the first elements of which are used _directly_ in the changed code above, instead of through their equivalence. Would that not work as I expect it?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues No, I am definitely not bound to the fixed format. But like @VladimirF said, I will change things one step at a time. In fact, I am going to use [plusFORT](https://www.polyhedron.com/plusfort7) to take care of most of the translation to F90 after getting rid of the `equivalence` statements.

Comment: 89 characters are too many in Fortran 77 (more generally, fixed-form source).

Comment: In the first version you have that the (blank) common block has two scalars: `X1` and `X2`.  In the second version the blank common block has two arrays `COM1` and `COM2`, each with `NCOM` elements. If `NCOM` is not `1` those two specifications are different.

Comment: @francescalus Ah, now I see what you mean. And you're right! That is weird. This is how the original source had done it. They declare local arrays of length `ncom`, and global (`common`) scalars, and equivalence the first elements of the local arrays to the global scalars. But then they do proceed to use the arrays as well in the functions which include this file. Does that mean the content of those arrays are then unique and independent to each function including this file (with the exception of the first elements, because those are `common`)?

Comment: Looks like I neglected something pretty important about the first common statement: because `x1` and `x2` are in common and the equivalence, you actually have an association between the array elements of `com1` and `com2` (`com1(2)` is the same lump of memory as `com2(1)`) .  The second version doesn't capture this.  If you want more information about that, I'd suggest trying to get a question zooming in on that.

Comment: @francescalus Well, actually, it turns out I also forgot an important difference. The two scalars, `x1` and `x2`, are actually written as `common/v_var1/ x1` and `common/v_var2/ x2`. In this case the link you described between the elements of `com1` and `com2` does not exist.

Comment: From [F2008 Standard, section 3.3.3](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) _In fixed source form, there are restrictions on where a statement may appear within a line. **If a source line contains only characters of default kind, it shall contain exactly 72 characters;** otherwise, its maximum number of characters is processor dependent._

Comment: In case the conversion of old (legacy) Fortran to a modern style is the main topic, this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.fortran might also be useful (more suited for long posts and discussion, e.g., using a link to external codes in Github/Gist etc)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, the error arises after refactoring the code probably because you are working in [fixed-form](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_structure_and_style) and the source line cannot go beyond 72 characters (all the remaining characters are ignored).

If you are modernizing the code, you should left fixed-form behind and write in free-form. Sometimes compilers assume source-form based on file extension. If this is the case, you can change the file extension from `.f` to `.f90`. Or else, you can pass the desired format as a compiler flag (`-ffree-form` in gfortran, `-free` in Intel Fortran).

If by any case you are stuck into fixed-form, you'd better do a line-continuation by putting an arbitrary non-blank character at column 6 of the continued line.